# How can I prove that $ p_{x,y}^{(n)}=P(X_n=y|X_0=x)$?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ a probability space.

Let $E$ be a countable set and $\Bbb P:=(p_{x,y})_{x,y\in E}$ a stochastic matrix (i.e. $p_{x,y}\ge0$ and $\sum_{y\in E}p_{x,y}=1$) and $\mu$ a probability on $E$.
We know that then there exists a Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n\ge0}$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ and it's such that
$$
P(X_{k+1}=y|X_k=x)=p_{x,y}\;\;\forall x,y\in E,\;\;\forall k\ge0\;.
$$

Let then $\Bbb P^n=(p_{x,y}^{(n)})_{x,y\in E}$ be the $n$-th power of the matrix $\Bbb P$.

We know that
$$
p_{x,y}^{(n)}=\sum_{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\in E}p_{x,x_1}p_{x_1,x_2}\dots p_{x_{n-1}y}\;\;.
$$

How can I prove that
$$
p_{x,y}^{(n)}=P(X_n=y|X_0=x)\;\;\;?
$$
I think it shouldn't be difficult, but I'm stuck.

I tried to see the case $n=2$, but after writing
\begin{align*}
p_{x,y}^{(2)}
&=\sum_{z\in E}p_{x,z}p_{z,y}\\
&=\sum_{z\in E}P(X_1=z|X_0=x)P(X_2=y|X_1=z)
\end{align*}
I don't know how can I handle this.

Can someone help me? Many thanks

Comment: You're almost there... Swap the factors of the terms in your last sum, then you see that you sum over all possible ways to go from $X_0=x$ to $X_2=y$ -- the sums goes over all the possible values that $X_1$ might take. The result of the sum is thus $P(X_2=y|X_0=x)$, as desired...

Comment: First of all thanks! Then: you're saying to write
$$
\sum_{z\in E}P(X_1=z|X_0=x)P(X_2=y|X_1=z)=\sum_{z\in E}P(X_2=y|X_1=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x)
$$
but I don't see how to conclude with this! Why should this be $P(X_2=y|X_0=x)$?

Comment: Because $P(X_2=y|X_1=z)P(x_1=z|X_0=x)$ is the probability of transitioning from $x$ to $z$, and then to $y$. Summing those probabilities up for all *possible* values of $z$ gives you the probability of transitioning from $x$ to $y$ in *two* steps, i.e. $P(X_2=y|X_0=x)$.

Comment: @fgp: many thanks. Is there an algebraic way to see that $P(X_2=y|X_1=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x)$ is the probability of transitioning from $x$ to $z$ and *then* to $y$?

Comment: see the answer I just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a formal derivation, you need three facts.

The first is the identity $$
  P(A|B) = \frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}.
$$

The second a defining property Markov Chains, namely that $$
  P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} \,|\, X_0=x_0,\,\ldots,\, X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1} \,|\, X_n=x_n),
$$
i.e. that $X_n$ contains just as much information about $X_{n+1}$ as the whole history $X_0,\,\ldots,\,X_n$ does.

The third is that if $A = A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_n$, and all the $A_i$ are disjoint, then $$
  P(A) = P(A_1) + \ldots + P(A_n),
$$
and the same holds if you add an arbitrary $B$ as a precondition, i.e. $$
  P(A|B) = P(A_1\,|\,B) + \ldots + P(A_n\,|\,B).
$$

Using the first two identities, you get $$\begin{eqnarray}
P(X_2=y\,|\,X_1=z)P(X_1=z\,|\,X_0=x)
&=& P(X_2=y\,|\,X_1=z,X_0=x)P(X_1=z\,|\,X_0=x) \\
&=& \frac{P(X_2=y,X_1=z,X_0=x)}{P(X_1=z,X_0=x)}\cdot\frac{P(X_1=z,X_0=x)}{P(X_0=x)} \\
&=& \frac{P(X_2=y,X_1=z,X_0=x)}{P(X_0=x)} \\
&=& P(X_2=y,X_1=z|X_0=x).
\end{eqnarray}$$

The third identity then yields $$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{z} P(X_2=y\,|\,X_1=z)P(X_1=z\,|\,X_0=x)
&=& \sum_{z} P(X_2=y,X_1=z|X_0=x) \\
&=& P(X_2=y\,|\,X_0=x).
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Many many many thanks. Handling $P(X_2=y|X_1=z)P(X_1=z|X_0=x)$ I didn't use the Markov Property. It's the first time for me with the MC, hence I have to take familiarity. Once read "...a defining property of the MC" I immediately linked, and all turned clear. Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $\lambda_0$ is a position vector, we know that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_0\mathbb{P}$.
It follows that $\lambda_2 = \lambda_1\mathbb{P} = \lambda_0\mathbb{P}^2$

Induction can show that $\lambda_n = \lambda_0\mathbb{P}^n$